# Google Maps Marker Not Appearing on Main Map ONLY

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps api to create a small, stripped down map that shows a geocoded location with a marker.  You can see the live code here: http://www.ddbeadworks.com/

It works flawlessly, until someone clicks the Google logo to take themselves to maps.google.com.  There, the map is properly zoomed and centered on the location, but the marker isn't being passed to maps.google.com, it seems, as that doesn't appear?  I looked through the API, but I can't find anything like "markersToGoogle boolean" or any such variable.

Here is the relevant code section. This is the only place I deal with markers anywhere.  JavaScript:

```
var address = $(this).attr("name");
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                var yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': yourStartLatLng, 'bounds': true});
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 14)
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'disableDefaultUI', true)
            }
    });//close geocoder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what the Google logo links to, the main [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) web site, with the same center and zoom as the map it came from.

If you want to make a bigger map with your marker on it, you need to link to a bigger Google Maps API v3 based map (and not expect your user to use the "Google" logo).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, this answer just came in first.  I'll go make a big map page.